# Angular 5 curly braces issue

Tags: angular, templates, angular5

After upgrading my app from angular v2 to v5, I faced some strange behavior with templates curly braces. If template element uses curly braces - nothing would be displayed without any console errors.
For example:

```
<span>{{ 1 + 1 }}</span>
<span>{{ 'Test' }} test</span>
<span>Test</span>
```

would be rendered to

```
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span>Test</span>
```

There are no errors in console and existing component functions binded on (click) works perfectly normal. I really would be grateful for some hint or direction - what can cause such behavior

some thoughts: I guess it's somehow related to router-outlet, cause outside of  component, template renders as expected

---

Update: I don't know what exactly the problem was, but the it is definitely related to angular Router. I came out with 2 possible solutions:
1) Downgrading angular to v 4.1
2) Wrapping this.router.navigate method into this._ngZone.run(() => { })
So when using

```
this._ngZone.run(() => { this.router.navigate(['/app']) });
```

template renders as expected. Still would be great to know what was wrong with the original code.

Answer (score 0):

I try this code
and get perfect output.

```
2 Test test Test
```

Comment: Well, yes, it's obviously smth wrong with my app code, but i have no clue, what's wrong